# Any conflicts using Docker Toolbox for Mac and Already-Installed Virtualbox?

Tags: macos, docker, virtualbox, boot2docker

I have Virtualbox already installed on a Mac El Capitan machine running several VMs that I need to continue to use. I understand that Docker Toolbox will install its own Virtualbox.

I'd like to not disrupt my existing VMs. Is there any possibility that the two Virtualbox installations would conflict and if so, are there any known remedies?

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Docker Toolbox on my Macbook Pro running El Captian 10.11.4. I had VirtualBox 5.0.8 already installed and working properly. When Docker Toolbox automatically recognized this VirtualBox installation and started using it without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install docker toolbox: you can install docker machine and kinematic separately.
[`docker machine`](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases) installation is straight-forward (just copy the executable)

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.5.5/docker-machine_darwin-amd64 >/usr/local/bin/docker-machine && \
  chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

You might want to upgrade your VirtualBox to the latest version though.